# Where is the label language used for Isabelle defined?

Tags: label, isabelle

I'm reading through some proofs written in Isabelle and I find a label syntax which I don't know really where it comes from. See for instance [this](https://github.com/seL4/isabelle/blob/master/src/HOL/Decision_Procs/ex/Commutative_Ring_Ex.thy) link.  I'm thinking of the meaning of labels like `\<guillemotleft>` which is not self evident.

Can you tell me for instance what this label does and how can i see its definition / description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to read Isabelle theories in Isabelle/jEdit. What you're wondering about are so called "symbols". On disk, they are represented as LaTeX-like commands, but in the editor, they appear rendered.

If you don't have an installation of Isabelle at hand, you can also go to our Jenkins instance and see the theories in rendered form. 
[Here's your example.](https://ci.isabelle.systems/jenkins/job/isabelle-repo-makeall/ws/browser_info/HOL/HOL-Decision_Procs/Commutative_Ring_Ex.html)

Symbols can be (and are heavily) customised. If you want to find out where a symbol comes from, you can hover over it or click it while keeping Ctrl pressed.